# MySQL query not giving expected results

Tags: mysql

I am new to MySQL and I am trying to solve a problem for a project.

I have three tables: cars, sales and customers.
cars has VID as pk and some other attributes like model and price.
customers has CID as pk and some attributes.
sales has (VID,CID) as pk and a sales price and sales date as attributes.

The question is: "What is the model of car, that was sold most often in 2014"?

Here is my query

```
Select Model
From Cars,Sales
Where Cars.VID=Sales.VID
Group By Cars.VID 
Having MAX( (Select count(*)
         From Cars,Sales Where Cars.VID=Sales.VID AND SellDate Between  '2014-01-01' And '2014-12-30'));
```

I still get all the models, that exist in the sales table, 
Could tell me what is wrong?

Answer (score 1):

First:  *Never* use commas in the `FROM` clause.  *Always* use explicit, proper, standard `JOIN` syntax with an appropriate `ON` clause.

If you want only one such model, the simplest way is `ORDER BY` and `LIMIT`:

```
Select c.Model
From Cars c JOIN
     Sales s
     on c.VID = s.VID
where s.SellDate >=  '2014-01-01' And
      s.SellDate < '2015-01-01'
Group By c.Model
Order by count(*) desc
limit 1;
```

Additional notes:

- The columns in the `GROUP BY` should match the unaggregated columns in the `SELECT`, pretty much *always*.
- Use table aliases that are abbreviations of the table names.
- Qualify all column names, so you (and others) know where they come from.
- Note the change in the date arithmetic.  Last I heard, 2014-12-31 was in 2014 (your business rules may be different).  I prefer `<` to `between`, in case the "date" column also has a time stamp.

Comment: for what reason is the limit 1 used?

Comment: @antonisarvanitis, cause you asked in question *What is the model of car* and not *What are the models of car*